# how to deploy project on remote server by using pm2 deploy?

Tags: node.js, pm2

[image]

When i use git clone this project on remote server, It can work, but i use pm2 deploy, it tells me there are some errors, I really confuse. Somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolve it by use 'ssh_options': 'ForwardAgent=yes' !!!